# aiohttp implicitly turns out my method to function

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My aiohttp middleware gets function as parameter instead of bound method which have been passed to route. How to explain this behavior? How to avoid that?

```
class AsyncHttpServer:

    def __init__(self, host=None, port=None, loop=None, conf_path=None):
        self.loop = loop
        self.conf_path = conf_path
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.loop = loop
        self.app = web.Application(
            middlewares=[
                preprocess_request,
            ]
        )

    def serve_forever(self):

        with RequestHandler(self.conf_path) as handler:
            print(handler.search)  # bound method 'search'. Instance is irrelevant
            self.app.router.add_routes([                   
                web.post('/search', handler.search, name='search'),                   
            ])
            try:
                web.run_app(self.app, port=self.port, host=self.host, loop=self.loop)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass

@asyncio.coroutine
@middleware
def preprocess_request(request, handler):
    print(handler) # function 'search'
```

Comment: This is how `asyncio.coroutine` works.

Comment: You mean that aiohttp wraps my middleware in coroutine decorator without any assistance? I take opportunity to say "thank you" for your contributions.

Comment: Look on your example. You explicitly wrapped `preprocess_request` by `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator.

Comment: The point is nothing changes when i remove coroutine decorator.

Comment: In debug mode (`PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG`) it matters.
Or just use `async` / `await` syntax.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more question (sorry): is there possibility to call handler's object at middleware if handlers organized with class?

Comment: Answer comment is not a good place for asking new question.
But simple answer is -- yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If handlers are organized with class and have been passed to route, *aiohttp* wraps those handlers with decorators using *partial.wraps* and makes it like usual functions. So it is impossible to use this functions as object methods directly.

They can be used as methods only after unwrapping:

```
handler.__wrapped__.__self__
```

or handlers class may be passed as web.Application() value because it have MutableMapping protocol:

```
with RequestHandler(self.conf_path) as handler:
        self.app["handler"] = handler
```

and may be called like:

```
class_handler = request.app["handler"]
```